# Can two nodes have different contract version but same flow?

Tags: corda

Is it possible for 2 nodes to communicate if they have different state version but same flow version?

I have a case where there may be N number of nodes in the network, and some nodes may upgrade slower than others.

i.e Node A has `ObligationV1` and NodeB has upgraded to `ObligationV2` but the same `flow-cordapp` is deployed on both.

1. Can this work?
2. Can a common flow handle different versions of state creations? (assuming the sequence of send/receive is the same)
3. Can the network operator / responder blacklist the V1?
4. If this works, does it mean if NodeA is initiator and NodeB is responder, then the states created are V1. Vice versa, then it becomes V2 ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it should work. Like how we see with the new CorDapp templates, flows are independent of the CorDapp containing states and contracts.

2) Yes, that shouldn't be a problem. The new states will be of a different type.

3) Not right now, the whitelist is append-only. This may change with signature constraints which are in the works.

4) It's entirely up to you - NodeB would still have V1 in their classpath and could continue to create V1 states.